# How to use bazel build a custom toolchain use a compiler installed at custom location?

Tags: bazel

According to the wiki https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain, I can use bazel build hello.cc code. Now I have Installed the croos-tool compiler in local disk. So I want to create a custom CROSSTOOL use new_local_repository. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a custom CROSSTOOL, and you have compiler/linker already installed, just follow the instructions in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain and when you're done, you can use your crosstool by e.g. `bazel build --crosstool_top=//tools/my_custom_crosstool:toolchain //src:hello`.

Comment: For  example,  assuming cross-tool compiler have installed, it located in /usr/local/ARM-toolchain/gcc-linaro-6.1.1-2016.08-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/, now I want to use the local repository.  Then I change the WORKSPACE file.   Now the parameter url = '[/usr/local/ARM-toolchain/gcc-linaro-6.1.1-2016.08-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/shell/bazel/testdata/bazel_toolchain_test_data/WORKSPACE.linaro)',all right? thanks!

Comment: You have to use https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#local_repository or https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository for local files.

Comment: It is cool. Thanks for your help!